# CLOSED - Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:run

Tags: spring, maven, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I try to run a Spring Cloud Data Flow app with a Kafka message broker but the `mvn spring-boot:run` always fail..
`Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-data-flow-server: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V -> [Help 1]`

Does someone know this issue?

Here is my log :

```
[WARNING]java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext (BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent (BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent (BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared (EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared (SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment (SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at org.baeldung.spring.cloud.springdataflowserver.SpringDataFlowServerApplication.main (SpringDataFlowServerApplication.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.734 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-31T17:01:58+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-data-flow-server: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.baeldung.spring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-flow-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-starter-parent</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dataflow local server dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is the MainClass :

```
package org.baeldung.spring.cloud.springdataflowserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.EnableDataFlowServer;

@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDataFlowServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(
                SpringDataFlowServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is the Baeldung tuto (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-data-flow-stream-processing)
I've tried everything I've found on the Internet, but nothing worked..
Even if I try a `mvn -X spring-boot:run` with the Baeldung code, I've the same issue..

PS 01/02/2018 :
I've updated my pom.xml and that fixed the issue. Here is my new pom.xml (changed the version of Spring Boot)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.16.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.baeldung.spring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-flow-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-starter-parent</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dataflow local server dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The versions of data flow server and Spring Boot are not compatible.

Have a look at the versions here:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/releases

The latest version of the server is 1.7.3.RELEASE and this release is based on Spring Boot 1.5.16.

Comment: I've changed the Spring Boot version to "1.5.16.RELEASE" : works fine ;)
Thanks